# Excel how to grab from a single column search result the whole row of data

Tags: excel, vba, database, search-box

If the title is vague I am sorry, I have an single textbox1 where you type part of what you are looking for and it will show all matches containing what you filled in. But now, when you found what you where looking for and it is selected, I want to automatically pull all data out of the row of the selected result, to the correct textbox's.

I have 10 columns, each column in order: ID, serial number, message, number, area, date, status, function, name, description. (they don't match with the picture, I sort of translated it)
I am trying to create an database for issues of certain machines, but I am stuck and have litterly no clue how to do this.

Worse:
This searching feature is in an new form, the main form which contains the textbox's for all data is called [MyUserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZCmd.png) , the looks will be change, and the [search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEBkN.png) is called UserForm1, when the data is selected I want to pull it to those textboxs on the other form.

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Me.TextBox1.Value = ListBox1.Value
ListBox1.Visible = False

End Sub

Function search_text(textTosearch As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Boolean
Dim xvalue As String

Me.ListBox1.Clear
Me.ListBox1.Height = 54

For i = 2 To 501
    xvalue = Cells(i, 3).Value
    
    If LCase(xvalue) Like LCase(textTosearch) & "*" = True Then
        If x = False Then
            Me.ListBox1.Visible = True
            x = True
        End If
    
        If xvalue <> "" Then
           Me.ListBox1.AddItem xvalue
        End If
        
        If Me.ListBox1.Height < 260 Then
            Me.ListBox1.Height = Me.ListBox1.Height + 10
        End If
        
    End If
Next

If Me.ListBox1.ListCount <= 0 Then
    Me.ListBox1.Visible = False
End If

End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    search_text Me.TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ListBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

**Update**
I did this, it seems to work, if you guys still got tips yes please!

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
MyUserForm.show
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

Me.TextBox1.Value = ListBox1.Value
ListBox1.Visible = False

End Sub

Function search_text(textTosearch As String)
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Boolean
Dim xvalue As String

Me.ListBox1.Clear
Me.ListBox1.Height = 54

For i = 2 To 501
    xvalue = Cells(i, 3).Value
    
    If LCase(xvalue) Like LCase(textTosearch) & "*" = True Then
        If x = False Then
            Me.ListBox1.Visible = True
            x = True
        End If
    
        If xvalue <> "" Then
           Me.ListBox1.AddItem xvalue
        End If
        
        If Me.ListBox1.Height < 260 Then
            Me.ListBox1.Height = Me.ListBox1.Height + 10
        End If
        
    End If
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = TextBox1.Text Then
        MyUserForm.txtDriveNo = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        MyUserForm.txtMessage = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        MyUserForm.txtNumber = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        MyUserForm.cbArea = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5).Value
        MyUserForm.txtDatum = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
        MyUserForm.cbStatus = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value
        MyUserForm.cbFunctie = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8).Value
        MyUserForm.txtNaam = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
        MyUserForm.txtBeschrijving = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value
    End If

Next

If Me.ListBox1.ListCount <= 0 Then
    Me.ListBox1.Visible = False
End If

End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    search_text Me.TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ListBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: A couple of tips not related to the problem or its solution: 1) you can use a [With-End With](https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) instead of typing everytime MyUserForm. In this case it wont' give you much of an advantage, but i still inform you in case you didn't know. 2) I highly recommend to use not single letter variable like `x`. Use variables names at least 3 letters long which you won't find in the rest of the code. For example `xyz` is ok or `tr1`; do not use `Sel` or `She` or `Val` because you will most [...]

Comment: [...] likely find them in the rest of the code (in word like `Select` or `Sheet` or `Value`). It's also a good practice to add a tag to the name to remind you of what kind of variable it is. I use 3 letters long tags like `Rng` for ranges or `Dbl` for doubles. Others use single letter tags like `o` for objects.